# Error org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, android, date-format, threetenbp

I know that there is a lot of similar questions like this but cant apply these solutions on them.
i am trying to transform date that i am getting from server int this format: `2019-07-26T02:39:32.4053394` and then i am trying to convert it to milliseconds like this:

```
private long convertTimeInMilliseconds(String date){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT);
    return OffsetDateTime.parse(date, formatter)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();

}
```

in my onCreate i call this method:

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(convertTimeInMilliseconds("2019-07-26T02:39:32.4053394"));
```

but keep getting `Caused by: org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-07-26T02:39:32.4053394' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19`
on .toInstant()
I think that problem is in my formatter, but do not know how to solve this

Comment: By the way, you may not need to use the *ThreeTen-Backport* for older Android. The latest Android tooling brings most of the *java.time* functionality to older Android via “API desugaring”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDateTime
.parse( "2019-07-26T02:39:32.4053394" )
.atZone( 
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) 
)
.toInstant()
.getEpochMilli()
```

## Wrong formatting pattern

Your input string has a fractional second. But your formatting pattern says to expect only whole seconds. So your formatting pattern does not match your input. Hence your error.

## Wrong type

Your input string lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. You should parse such input as a `LocalDateTime`.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

### ISO 8601

Your input complies with the ISO 8601 standard for text formats. The standard formats are used by default in *java.time* when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-07-26T02:39:32.4053394" ) ;
```

### Not a moment

Understand that such a value is inherently ambiguous. We cannot know if that text is meant to represent 2 AM in Tokyo Japan, 2 AM in Toulouse France, or 2 AM in Toledo Ohio US — all different moments, several hours apart. So a `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

Never use `LocalDateTime` to track when something specific has happened. To track a moment, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

## Determine a moment

If you know for certain that text was meant to represent a moment in a certain time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Then extract an `Instant` to adjust to UTC, and get your count of milliseconds since epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

If your input string was meant to represent a moment as seen in UTC, apply `ZoneOffset.UTC` to get a `OffsetDateTime`. Then extract an `Instant`, and get your count of epoch millis.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]